# Correlated random effects in a linear mixed model

Tags: regression, mixed-model, random-effects-model

How does a linear mixed model (LMM) deal with correlated random effects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Random effects are typically modeled as normal random variables, so a generalization to multivariate normal with a variance covariance matrix is quite natural. The [lme4 vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf) (page 7) states that this generalization is the default for the popular R package:

> By default, lme4 assumes that all coefficients associated with the same random-effects term
>   are correlated.

You can also see on page 31 the use of the `VarCorr` function to extract the estimated variance matrix from a fitted model.